# macros expanding to a TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-node

I want to create rectangular nodes, given two coordinates `bottom left` and `top right`, with a macro. The difficult part is that I want to use the macro where a node name can be used; for example, in the place `current page` is the code below.

This code doesn't work but it shows the syntax I would like to use. Is it possible to do something similar?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand\makenode[2]{
  \node[fit={#1}{#2}] {}
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\coordinate (bottom left) at (10,10);
\coordinate (top right) at (20,20);

\node[anchor=south] at (\makenode{bottom left}{top right}.center) {My node text};
\node[anchor=south] at (current page.center) {My node text};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\path (bottom left) -- (top right) node[anchor=south,midway] {My node text};` does what your command is supposed to do. In any case, your attempt cannot work since `\makenode` generates a node (rather than yielding a name of a node object).

Answer (score 1):

See if the following MWE is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand\makenode[2]{\node[draw=red,         % to show node border, should be removed
                              inner sep=0pt,
                              fit=(#1) (#2)]}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[overlay, remember picture]
\coordinate (bl)    at (5,5);   % bottom left
\coordinate (tr)    at (10,10); % top right

\makenode{bl}{tr} {my node text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, this approach to define node will have problems when the text in node is longer than horizontal distance between defined coordinates and when you like to have text in two or more lines.

**Addendum:**
Solution as suggested @Ignasi in comment below answer. Considering it, the code of images which has more similar nodes, can be more easy to draw and connect with arrows:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand\makenode[2]{\node[draw=red,         % to show node border, should be removed
                              inner sep=0pt,
                              fit=(#1) (#2)]}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
MN/.style args = {#1/#2}{         % MakeNode
                         draw=red, inner sep=0pt, fit=(#1) (#2)}
                        ]
\coordinate (bl)    at (5,5);   % bottom left
\coordinate (tr)    at (10,10); % top right

\node (mn) [MN=bl/tr] {my node text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: I would propose to replace the `\newcommand` by a `tikzstyle` which contains the `fit` definition. This way it's possible to use something like `\node[rectangle={left corner}{right corner}, ....]` and all problems with customization of text, colors, etc. will disappear.

Comment: @Ignasi, you are right. Today I would go with this way. But in time of question, which ask for defining `\newcommand` ... I just follow OP wish. I will write addendum which will consider your suggestion ASAP.