# Generate TikZ Node with a macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-node

Inspired by this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510539/macros-expanding-to-a-tikz-node), I tried to wrap this normal node...

```
\node[fill=blue!20,shape=ellipse, draw=black] (nodename) at(0,0){\begin{tabular}{l}
    Main Text\\ \hline
    extension point: \\ 
    Some Text
\end{tabular}};
```

...into these kind of macro:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    umlusecaseext/.style n args = {3}{
        shape=ellipse,
        fill=blue!20,
        draw=black,
        code={
            \begin{tabular}{l}
                #1\\ \hline
                #2: \\ 
                #3
            \end{tabular} 
        }
    }]
\node (example) [umlusecaseext={{Main Text},{extension point},{Some Text}}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My goal is to reuse this node. Unfortunately this did not work. Can you correct my solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set the contents of a node via style, use `node contents`.

If you define a style via `.style n args={3}{…}` you simply must use three arguments delimited by curly brackets (no `,` and no all encompassing `{{}{}{}}`).

If you use `node contents` you should remove the empty `{}` (because at that point it will be a normal path specification) – it doesn't break anything but it is better to remove it (and make it clear that the nodes content must come from a style).

Note: If you `node contents` you can't specify anything additional after the `]` in regards to the node (no name, no position, no further styles).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    umlusecaseext/.style n args = {3}{
        shape=ellipse,
        fill=blue!20,
        draw=black,
        node contents={
            \begin{tabular}{l}
                #1\\ \hline
                #2:\\ 
                #3
            \end{tabular} 
        }
    }]
\node (example) [umlusecaseext={Main Text}{extension point}{Some Text}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]